# How to draw sharp lines in texture paint?

Tags: texturing

I wanted to draw this kind of line, and adjusted Falloff as the manual says, but doing so just made the line thinner or blurry. I don't get the effect I want. What should I do?
My version is 2.82.

[image]

Comment: Hello, I think this is for Grease Pencil, not Texture Paint, are you talking about Grease Pencil? https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/grease_pencil/modes/draw/tools/curve.html

Comment: As mentioned by moonboots ... you [paint texture](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/sculpt_paint/brush/falloff.html), but your reference is pointing to [Grease Pencil](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/grease_pencil/modes/draw/tools/line.html) that is totally different thing (based as object).

Comment: Sorry. I made a mistake.
So is there a way to draw sharp lines in texture drawing?

Comment: To draw sharp line on texture you have to switch to "Constant" (last profile on right side at bottom) and use tablet pressure for fall-off.

Comment: Thanks, what I want is lines with thin edges like the picture on the left, and if I choose Constant, I can only draw lines with the same thickness as the picture on the right.